# Jquery, set value of td in a table?

Tags: jquery

I create dynamic a table with `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. One of the td tags gets the id "detailInfo". I have an onclick function on some button. I would like to set some value in the td "detailInfo" after pressing on the button.

So how can I set the value of the td with id "detailInfo" ?

This is the td:

```
<td id="detailInfo" rowspan="2" width="300px">picture detail</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "set some value"? `td` tags doesn't have value. Are you trying to append some text?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I mean the html value.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

use `.html()` along with selector to get/set HTML:

```
 $('#detailInfo').html('changed value');
```

Answer (score 11):

From:

- [Manipulation | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

it could be:

`.html()`

In an HTML document, `.html()` can be used to get the contents of any element.

`.text()`

Unlike the `.html()` method, `.text()` can be used in both XML and HTML documents. The result of the `.text()` method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

`.val()`

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. When called on an empty collection, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: `val` doesn't work for me (tho I'm using an old version of jQuery); `text` does.

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code:

```
$("Your button id or class").live("click", function(){

    $('#detailInfo').html('set your value as you want');

});
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below :

`$('#detailInfo').html('your value')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){ $("#detailInfo").html("WHAT YOU WANT") })
```